# Why am I getting the following errors?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get the following errors while executing some SQL code:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server WIN-ILO9GLLB9J0, Line 9
>   Incorrect syntax near 'name'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server WIN-ILO9GLLB9J0, Line 10
>   Incorrect syntax near 'name'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server WIN-ILO9GLLB9J0, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near 'name'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server WIN-ILO9GLLB9J0, Line 12
>   Incorrect syntax near 'name'.

My code is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE city
(
    id number(5), 
    name varchar2(17),
    countrycode varchar2(3),
    district varchar2(20),
    population number(20)
);

INSERT INTO city (id, 'name', 'countrycode', 'district', population) 
VALUES (3878, 'Scottsdale', 'USA', 'Arizona', 202705 );

INSERT INTO city (id, 'name', 'countrycode', 'district', population)    
VALUES (3965, 'Corona', 'USA', 'California', 124966);

INSERT INTO city (id, 'name', 'countrycode', 'district', population) 
VALUES (3973, 'Concord', 'USA', 'California', 121780);

INSERT INTO city (id, 'name', 'countrycode', 'district', population) 
VALUES (3977, 'Cedar', 'Rapids', 'USA', 'Iowa', 120758);

INSERT INTO city (id, 'name', 'countrycode', 'district', population) 
VALUES (3982, 'Coral Springs', 'USA', 'Florida', 117549);

SELECT * 
FROM city 
WHERE (population > 100000);
```

Comment: Also: SQL Server doesn't have a `Varchar2()` datatype - that's Oracle. In SQL Server, it's just `VARCHAR(n)` .....

Comment: Or a `number` datatype.

Answer (score 3):

Taking only one of your insert statements as an example, it should be altered to:

```
INSERT INTO city
  (id, name, countrycode, district ,population) 
values
  (3878,'Scottsdale', 'USA', 'Arizona', 202705 );
```

The `'` are removed around the column names as it would otherwise be interpreted as a string and not as the name of the column.

Answer (score 0):

When using SQL-Server, the following can be used when creating and inserting into table.

```
CREATE TABLE city
(
    id INT, 
    name VARCHAR(17),
    countrycode VARCHAR(3),
    district VARCHAR(20),
    population INT
);

INSERT INTO city (id, name, countrycode, district, population) VALUES
(3878, 'Scottsdale', 'USA', 'Arizona', 202705 ),
(3965, 'Corona', 'USA', 'California', 124966),
(3973, 'Concord', 'USA', 'California', 121780),
(3977, 'Cedar', 'Rapids', 'USA', 'Iowa', 120758),
(3982, 'Coral Springs', 'USA', 'Florida', 117549);

SELECT * 
  FROM city 
 WHERE population > 100000;
```